# Smalltalk compilers that target either Java, .NET or Ruby

Tags: java, .net, ruby-on-rails, compiler-construction, smalltalk

Looking for a Smalltalk compiler that given Smalltalk (Instantiations) will emit either Java bytecode, .NET CLR or Ruby. Not looking for porting utilities as I want to leave the application in Smalltalk.

I have googled for solutions and ran across a company who had a website (http://www.smalltalkmigrations.com/) but it seems as if they are no longer in business and looking for other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems, James Ladd is working on a Smalltalk for the JVM, but it has not yet been releases.

You can follow the project on twitter though: https://twitter.com/smalltalkjvm

Answer (score 2):

For .Net versions ...

- ## SmallTalk http://www.refactory.com/Software/SharpSmalltalk/
- IronSmallTalk http://www.codeplex.com/IronSmalltalk

Comment: IronSmalltalk looks dead already, and there were no usable releases at all. #SmallTalk hasn't been updated since 2003. Sadly...

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it before, but [Bistro](http://bistro.sourceforge.net/) is a Smalltalk variant that runs on the JVM.

Comment: hmm... Last Updated: April 21, 2002

Comment: Version 3.6 , Date  
 14 October 2010. 8.5 years between 3.5, 3.6!